# Can only use python object in functions with self, not directly in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I've been learning python, and making some simple Gui's with Gtk. I'm trying to learn how classes and objects work, but I had a problem which I just can't understand.

I used an example with Gtk labels and buttons, and inside the method connected to the button, I can change the text on the label. But I wanted to change the text on the label at the start of the program, not when clicking a button.

When I tried to set the label text directly in the class, I got the error "AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'set_label'". I already solved it by making an init function which sets the label there. But I don't understand why it's not possible directly in the object. "label_status" seems to exist, but it doesn't have the function I want to use.

I understand that the methods get passed the instance of the object, so I can use the stuff from the object inside the methods with "self". So in my understanding, "self" refers to the instance object, and I can access everything in it. So why can't I use the same thing directly in the object, without "self"?

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio, Gtk

import sys
import time
import ctypes

@Gtk.Template.from_file("glade.glade")
class AppWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    __gtype_name__ = "app_window"

    label_status: Gtk.Entry = Gtk.Template.Child()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.label_status.set_label("test 1") # This works <


    label_status.set_label("test 2") # This does NOT work <


    @Gtk.Template.Callback()
    def button_connect_clicked_cb(self, widget):

        self.label_status.set_label("test 3") # This works <


class Application(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, application_id="dev.snap7.Gtk1",
                         flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE, **kwargs)
        self.window = None

    def do_activate(self):
        self.window = self.window or AppWindow(application=self)
        self.window.present()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Did you try setting the value during the creation of the var : label_status = Gtk.Template.Child('test 4') . Class var declaration is not for coding just defining var with eventually initial value if possible In object init. In other case __init__ is where you can modify value or value of object vars.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but that was not what I was asking. I already fixed the problem by setting it in the init. I just would like to understand why I can only use set_label in methods/functions with self, and not directly in the object itself. Or is there a reason this isnt possible?

Comment: For my knowledge it is not possible to update a class outside function or using ‘object.var´ from outside class. I think no language enable this.